modbus RTU communication protocol in python
Even though the device is connected to the serial port corresponding to the controller, it gives an error message: "No response from instrument
No response from instrument" while reading the controller's register. The step is to first connect to controller and communicate with it then send commands to the linear motor connected with the controller.
Controller: RCM-P6GW-EP  (IAI Corporation)
Linear Motor: RCP-6S
RCB-CV-UCB converter
This is the code i took from YouTube channel: Modbus RTU Master Implementation in Python - Read Data from Modbus RTU Slave
Brighterside Tech'
which is similar to the Modbus system i am using.
#code
import minimalmodbus
import serial
import sys
import time

# Set up the serial communication
port = 'COM3'
slave_id = 1

try:
    instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument(port = port, slaveaddress = slave_id)
    print("Connected to instrument")

    instrument.serial.baudrate = 9600
    instrument.serial.bytesize = 8
    instrument.serial.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
    instrument.serial.stopbits = 1
    instrument.serial.timeout = 0.5

except:
    print(f"Couldn't connect to instrument via {port}")
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__== '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            data = instrument.read_register(1)
            print(f"Current value: {data}")
        except minimalmodbus.NoResponseError:
            print("No response from instrument")
        
        time.sleep(2)



Output:
Connected to instrument
No response from instrument
No response from instrument
No response from instrument
No response from instrument

Can't see anything obviouslly wrong with your code (other than that you are reading register 1 which the manual indicates is "Reserved for system"). I'd suggest testing with a known good tool first (e.g. mbpoll/modpolll) to confirm you don't have a wiring/config issue. Modbus manual for unit is here - see page 68 for a query sample.

I note that you have tagged this as modbus-rtu-over-tcp but state "connected to the serial port corresponding to the controller", so please add detail on how the unit is actually conencted.
